# Redshift small tables - what are they?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I see below queries in the stl_query table, what do they mean? when do they occur?

```
small table conversion: 3623965
small table validation: select sum(rows), sum(sorted_rows) from stv_tbl_perm where table = {tableid};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift checks the status of AUTO distributed tables periodically and converts the distribution type as needed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html

> **AUTO distribution**
>   With AUTO distribution, Amazon Redshift assigns an optimal distribution style based on the size of the table data. For example, Amazon Redshift initially assigns ALL distribution to a small table, then changes to EVEN distribution when the table grows larger. When a table is changed from ALL to EVEN distribution, storage utilization might change slightly. The change in distribution occurs in the background, in a few seconds. Amazon Redshift never changes the distribution style from EVEN to ALL. To view the distribution style applied to a table, query the PG_CLASS_INFO system catalog view. For more information, see Viewing Distribution Styles. If you don't specify a distribution style with the CREATE TABLE statement, Amazon Redshift applies AUTO distribution.

Comment: Thanks Joe, do these converts happen in the background? Does it have any impact on the performance, in the sense say queries are running using the table and while the conversion is happening does it need to wait until its completed? I see there are conversions taking 30-40s in the cluster.